# How to set up a network-manager service to configure a modem connection automatically?

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, dhcp, huawei-mobile-services, networkmanager

I try to connect USB Huawei E8372 modem on my Ubuntu 18.04. **dmesg** command gives an information:

```
[  371.616615] cdc_ether 1-6:1.0 eth0: register 'cdc_ether' at usb-0000:00:14.0-6, CDC Ethernet Device, 0c:5b:8f:27:9a:64
[  371.616948] usb-storage 1-6:1.2: USB Mass Storage device detected
[  371.617603] scsi host4: usb-storage 1-6:1.2
[  371.625478] cdc_ether 1-6:1.0 enx0c5b8f279a64: renamed from eth0
[  372.636698] scsi 4:0:0:0: Direct-Access     HUAWEI   TF CARD Storage  2.31 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[  372.637021] sd 4:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[  372.637270] sd 4:0:0:0: Power-on or device reset occurred
[  372.637965] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk
[  372.856712] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbserial_generic
[  372.856727] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for generic
[  372.860310] usbcore: registered new interface driver option
[  372.860325] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for GSM modem (1-port)
```

So I have the **enx0c5b8f279a64** interface. network-manager service adds this device (logs from `service network-manager status`):

```
[1561201979.1919] devices added (path: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-6/1-6:1.0/net/enx0c5b8f279a64, iface: enx0c5b8f279a64)
[1561201979.1919] device added (path: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-6/1-6:1.0/net/enx0c5b8f279a64, iface: enx0c5b8f279a64)
```

But I can't access the Internet. Moreover, **ifconfig** doesn't show this interface.

I can use **dhclient**:
`dhclient -v enx0c5b8f279a64`:

```
Listening on LPF/enx0c5b8f279a64/0c:5b:8f:27:9a:64
Sending on   LPF/enx0c5b8f279a64/0c:5b:8f:27:9a:64
Sending on   Socket/fallback
DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.8.100 on enx0c5b8f279a64 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x36f4d377)
DHCPNAK from 192.168.8.1 (xid=0x77d3f436)
DHCPDISCOVER on enx0c5b8f279a64 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0x5ad85374)
DHCPDISCOVER on enx0c5b8f279a64 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 7 (xid=0x5ad85374)
DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.8.100 on enx0c5b8f279a64 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x7453d85a)
DHCPOFFER of 192.168.8.100 from 192.168.8.1
DHCPACK of 192.168.8.100 from 192.168.8.1
bound to 192.168.8.100 -- renewal in 41121 seconds.
```

After that, I will access the Internet, and network-manager logs:

```
[1561202049.0339] device (enx0c5b8f279a64): carrier: link connected
[1561202049.0415] device (enx0c5b8f279a64): carrier: link connected
```

I want that network-manager service set up the interface of the modem automatically without any manual steps like running *dhclient*. How to do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ubuntu 18.04 netplan is used, just write for your interface enx0c5b8f279a64: "dhcp: true"" (see example here: https://netplan.io/examples)